# Height of div with property display:table same as parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make div with class name "data" same height as parent div ("strip1"), but unfortunately it is little shorter. It happens only on Chrome, but not on Firefox. What should I fix?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="strip1">
    <div class="data">
        <div class="data_element dataA">A</div>
        <div class="data_element dataB">B</div>
        <div class="data_element dataC">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="strip2"></div>
<div class="strip3"></div>
```

```
body{
   padding:0;
}

.strip2 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.strip3 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;

 }

.strip1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
.data {
    background-color: #00337C;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
.data_element {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 30px; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.data_element.dataA {    
    width: 20%;    
}
.data_element.dataB {
    width: 50%;
}
.data_element.dataC {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Here is example [live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQY4/1455/)

Comment: It seems to be a subpixel problem, e.g. `.strip1` is `165.5px` tall, and `.data` is `165px`. But when the height of `.strip1` is an integral amount of pixels, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.strip1` display to `display: table;`. You may also want to then change `.data` to `display: table-row;`. Setting the diaplay on .data to table-row will allow you to remove the height and width declarations.

**Edited:** Added snippet

```css
body{
    padding:0;
}

.strip2 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.strip3 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.strip1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
}

.data {
    background-color: #00337C;
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%; /* you can remove height declaration if set to display:table-row */
    width: 100%; /* you can remove width declaration if set to display:table-row */     
}

.data_element {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 30px; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.data_element.dataA {    
    width: 20%;    
}

.data_element.dataB {
    width: 50%;
}

.data_element.dataC {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="strip1">
        <div class="data">
            <div class="data_element dataA">A</div>
            <div class="data_element dataB">B</div>
            <div class="data_element dataC">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip2"></div>
    <div class="strip3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.data {
    background-color: #00337C;
    display: table;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```